# Scikit-Learn Custom Imputer with random value around mean value

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to create a Custom Imputer to replace `NaN` values in my data with a random value in the range of `mean - std` and `mean + std` for the column where the `NaN` value is in.

This is the code for the Imputer i have so far:

```py
class GroupImputer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        X = check_array(X, force_all_finite=False)
        self.means = np.nanmean(X, axis=0)
        self.stds = np.nanstd(X, axis=0)
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        check_is_fitted(self, 'means')
        check_is_fitted(self, 'stds')
        X = check_array(X, force_all_finite=False)
        # how do i apply to each row of the data?
        return 0
```

The `self.means` contains a list of the `means` for each column.

The `self.stds` contains a list of all `stds` for each column.

How do i apply a random value between `mean - std` and `mean + std` for each `NaN` in a row of the data?

Do i have to iterate through the data? (`for row in X:`) and pick the right mean and std according to the column index? Or is there a method which will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to iterate through the data, assume the number of rows and the number of columns of your data are 5 and 4, respectively

```
num_rows,num_cols = 5,4

# just fake two arrays of column means and stds
column_means = np.random.uniform(1,8,num_cols)
column_stds = np.random.rand(num_cols)

disp = np.random.uniform(column_means-column_stds,column_means+column_stds, size=(num_rows,num_cols))
```

The array `disp` is something like

```
array([[6.29377845, 6.56185572, 5.32590954, 2.14719305],
       [6.36648777, 6.97781432, 4.89773801, 2.21909144],
       [5.38109603, 6.70649396, 5.50100582, 2.26518757],
       [5.59764259, 6.90297057, 5.65199988, 2.25340505],
       [5.80928963, 6.4976407 , 5.23792109, 1.99580784]])
```

in which each column of this array is uniformly sampled from the range `(the column mean - the column std, the column mean + the column std)`. Therefore, the `NaN` entries of the original array can be replaced with the entries of `disp`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is a better option then iterate through the data.
You can create a uniformly random array (between the desired bounds) with the same shape) and replace every NaN value at index i with the random value at the same index.

```py
higher_bound = self.means + self.stds
lower_bound = self.means - self.stds
random_values = numpy.random.uniform(low=lower_bound, high=higher_bound , size=X.shape) #uniformly random array with the same shape
nan_mask = np.isnan(X) #indicates where is nan
X = np.where(nan_mask, random_values, X) #takes from random_values where nan_mask is true, else takes  from original array
```

Comment: Please consider editing this answer, adding an explanation to understand this code snippet. Doing so helps much more the OP!

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thanks to both of you